# Network's loss is steadily decreasing, accuracy remains at chance level

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning

I'm training a Resnet v2 straight out of the [TF repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/resnet_v2.py) on cifar-10 and I'm getting weird results.

The training loss starts out at ~2.4 and steadily decreases into the 1e-4 domain. However, accuracy remains constant at around 10% (cifar10 has 10 classes) and the evaluation loss starts high and diverges into NaN at some point.

I have [a log](https://pastebin.com/TxRid5KT) of 2x 100k steps, 64 batch size, 1e-3 learning rate showcasing the problem. (starts at line 43; always 1k steps, then 5k eval samples and repeat)

The problem originally arose when I modified the network and applied L1 regularisation, but now I have a vanilla network with no modifications and the problem still persists.

The code used to start the net:

```
#with slim.arg_scope(resnet_arg_scope()):
     logits, _ = resnet_v2_50(inputs=features, # inputs
                              num_classes=10, 
                              is_training=True, 
                              global_pool=True, 
                              output_stride=None, 
                              spatial_squeeze=True, 
                              reuse=None, 
                              scope='resnet_v2_50')
```

and the calculations for the predicted classes, loss, training operation and accuracy:

```
predicted_classes = tf.argmax(logits, 1)
[...]
loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits)
[...]
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=params.learning_rate)
varlist = [var for var in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)]
gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss, var_list=varlist)
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=gradients, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
[...]
'accuracy': tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels, predictions=predicted_classes)
```

The input data is used for other networks as well and yields a high accuracy on those, so that can't be it.

---

Loss without outliers

[image: loss without outliers]

Loss with outliers

[image: loss with outliers]

Comment: You say that you're using "2x 100k steps, 64 batch size, 1e-3 learning rate" -- are you sure that these are a good configuration? Moreover, in the lines of your log file, the lines that report accuracy also report that the loss is `inf`. Why is that? To me, it suggests that something is going wrong with how you're computing those statistics.

Comment: @Sycorax No, I'm not sure about that. I ran a grid search for 64-512 batch size and 1e0 - 1e-5 learning rates that came back with all 10% accuracies. Those are the specs that worked best for a medium sized convnet that scored ~80%+ on cifar. As for `inf`, I assume the number increases to the point where it hits the float ceiling, at which point it is displayed as `inf` until it gets too big to calculate with, then it changes to NaN. But I don't know how to verify that, the evaluation loss is calculated internally. I edited my question to provide the calculations for loss, accuracy and updating

Comment: `The problem originally arose when I modified the network and applied L1 regularisation, but now I have a vanilla network with no modifications and the problem still persists.`

This doesn't sound consistent. You're sure you're using the original code? There's no reason for it to start running differently if it's the same original code.

Comment: @AlexR. Yes, the problems persist both with the original code and with the vanilla adaptation. The surrounding framework is an estimator, but I fail to see how anything that is not listed above could influence the actual learning of the network...